# Service that repeatedly runs a method, after an amount of time

Tags: java, android, service, timer, alarmmanager

I want to create a service, that runs a method after 10 seconds over and over again, until I stop it, even if the app is closed. My attempted code is below

```
package com.example.tauben;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Reminder extends Service {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run(){
                f();
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);
    }

    public void f(){
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Service is still running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
   }

}
```

And this is how I start the service.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(Log_TAG,"_____________RESTART__________");

    Intent i= new Intent(this, Reminder.class);
    startService(i); 
}
```

The program just stops running immediately; how can I change my code to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a broadcast receiver that will start your service after receiving broadcast from `AlarmManager` :

```
public class SyncAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent data) {

    // set alarm to start service
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,  calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

    // start service after an hour
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 60);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    // set alarm to start service again after receiving broadcast
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(context, Reminder.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

start your broadcast receiver for the first time when you start your application:

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Also add this to your Manifest File:

```
<receiver android:name=".SyncAlarm" >
</receiver>
```

You should also have alook at this [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) if you want your service to be started by Android system as soon as resources are available instead of receiving Broadcast by AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try it this afternoon.

Comment: I dont really understand the code. I think it would be very helpful for me if you could tell me where i have to put witch code.

Comment: SyncAlaram is reusable class. just add it to your project. Add the 2nd block of code inside your `MainActivity` and the final block of code inside Manifest file. Here's a nice tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html that'll get you started with services incase you didn't get any of this. :)

Comment: and this one to get you started with broadcast receivers: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: Big Thanks. I hope I get it

Comment: Somehow i didnt get it to work. The methode of the service gets done one time, but i does not repeat.

Comment: right now its set to 60 minutes.. you should reduce the time for testing purpose.. make sure you have everything updated in manifest file. if it doesn't work just share the logs.